# Salesforce documentation URL structure change (July 2021)

Tags: discussion

Just pulled up some documentation for the String class again today (perhaps I'll eventually commit the entire contents to memory, but today is not that day), and noticed that Salesforce is rolling out a UI change for the documentation. Arguments about the intersection of information density and typography aside, there has been a change to the URL structure as well.

Looks like "apexcode" has been replaced with "apexref"

example

old:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_System_TriggerOperation.htm

new:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_enum_System_TriggerOperation.htm

Looks like the old URLs are set to redirect to the new ones, at least for the time being, but yeah, prime example of "links tend to change or go dead over time".

Not much to discuss here, I don't think. Just wanted to share the knowledge and suggest we update the canonical-qa resources.

Comment: The new help site is a disaster, but this isn't the place for that.  I will note that, at least for now, the old links are redirecting correctly.

Comment: why do you think the new [help](https://help.salesforce.com/) site is a disaster? really curious about this, where should/can we discuss?